How can I unpivot an Excel sheet to create a dashboard?

I have this sheet and I want to make analysis on this sheet like pivot tables to create pivot charts, and when the data is updated every weak this should affect the dashboard also, but when I convert data to a table it gives me a lot of nulls, I don't know how to deal with that, I think this is because the combined rows and columns and the date is so weird, Have I to restructure the data although this is not the best solution for the company.
I tried to convert the sheet to a table but it gives me a lot of nulls

This data is already highly manipulated and pivoted, so pivoting it further feels like the wrong direction. If anything, the data should be unpivoted so that it can better drive visualizations. I would expect an unpivoted version of this data to have the column headers: Location | Nationality | Description | Date | W where W holds the W1, W2, W3, and W4 values. I would remove the Totals from this restructured raw data, and then I would put charts on top of it (or an actual pivot table).

If I want to put new updates on the same sheet without convert it to a raw data and then automatically put this updates also in the raw data sheet is this possible ?,
Thanks so much for your help

And what do you think the proper way to unpivoting this sheet is it manually?

I think it would be a stretch to make it so that you can populate this sheet and have a more "raw data" sheet get updated automatically without some heavy formula work or maybe VBA. I think it might be best if you develop what you want as a dashboard for this data and then figure out how to wire that dashboard to this view of the data through formulas or other featuresets. I don't think there is any magic wand you can just hit this with and have it do exactly as you please.
